# cannot append to list in for loop (even though it works for another code right above)

Tags: python, list

So I have a code to basically loop through a few different arrays and then split according to training and testing indexes before storing the results in a train and test. However, when executing it, it returns an error for the test even though the exact same code is used for train

the code is as follow:

```
train = []
test = []
for i in ho:
    temp = newarr[i]
    #print(temp)
    #make overall list
    li = list(range(0,24))
    #get training indexes
    trgidx = list(random.sample(range(0,23),12))

    #get testing indexes
    tstidx = list(set(li).symmetric_difference(set(trgidx)))
    
    #extract training samples for the class
    for trg in trgidx:
        trgsample = temp[:,trg]
        train.append(trgsample)
    #extract testing samples 
    for test in tstidx:
        print(test)
        testsample = temp[:,test]
        test.append(testsample)
        
train = np.array(train).T
test = np.array(test).T
```

The error is shown at line 21;
ho is simply a list from [0,1,2,3] with each instance stored in the corresponding array, newarr

> 

```
 19         print(test)
 20         testsample = temp[:,test]
 21         test.append(testsample)
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Error is shown at line 21

The same code runs fine for the 'train' method, does anyone know where it's going wrong?

Comment: `for test in tstidx:` - same name `test` as the list `test`. Need to change one of the names.

Comment: ah right! didn't catch that all. thanks for pointing it out! can you post it as an answer? so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for test in tstidx:`

It has the same name test as the list `test`. Need to change one of the names.